# Javascript - Play two videos, one after the other, the second stay in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, video

Steps:

The first video play, when eds, the second video appears and play, when the second ends, play again the second (over and over again in a loop).

example:

- First video start
- First video end

Loop

- Second video start
- Second video end

html

```
<video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="myvideo" width="320" height="240" controls style="background:black">
</video>
```

js

```
var myvid = document.getElementById('myvideo');
var myvids = [
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4", 
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
  ];
var activeVideo = 0;

myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  // update the active video index
  activeVideo = (++activeVideo) % myvids.length;

  // update the video source and play
  myvid.src = myvids[activeVideo];
  myvid.play();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bnzqkpza/

Comment: Whats the issue? i tried the jsfiddle and this code works fine  as you wanted it with  no issues....

Comment: @mrtechtroid I need a loop of the second video. After the second video ends, I need that second video start again (over and again).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the following using a if statement in your event listener

```js
var myvid = document.getElementById('myvideo');
var myvids = [
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4", 
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
  ];
var activeVideo = 0;

myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
    if (activeVideo == 0){activeVideo = 1}
  myvid.src = myvids[activeVideo];
  myvid.play();
});
```

```html
<video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="myvideo" width="320" height="240" controls style="background:black">
</video>
```

Comment: works for me! thank you.

Comment: Consider Accepting The Answer if it helped you. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I read "click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in", but I can't see that check on my side, I can't.

Comment: Its Fine.......